# React: способы маршрутизации с помощью Route и Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Изучаю React. Во всех туториалах пишут, что для маршрутизации нужно использовать компонент Link. Мне он показался очень неудобным. Во-первых, он напрочь сбивает форматирование текста внутри кнопки, рисуя его как ссылку. Во-вторых, непонятно, как мне поступить, если я захочу изменить страницу по скрипту, как я это раньше делал с помощью location.href = ... ?

Comment: @entithat как это? а доку смотреть? в статьях написано наверняка что можно свой tag задать и что переход через редакс делается. Это все написано. Сам в своё время по статьям учил это все.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={'/'}>
   <button className='btn-regular btn-pager'>Главная страница</button>
</Link>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]